# parsing XML located inside the project

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, project

This is the first time i'm going to parse an XML file with Xcode and it differs a bit from what I'm used to... 
I read these 2 docs :

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/UsingParser.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/Articles/HandlingElements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002265-BCIJFGJI

I understand what's going on... But I still got one question.  How can I do to parse an XML file which is located directly inside the project (I mean, for example in the resource file, where I usually put my images?). They usually show how to get the url of the XML file..But it's not the case here. It's going to be loaded directly on the iPad, among images and everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Simply have to give the path of a local file :-

```
NSString *myFile= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"youFile.xml"]; 
NSURL *xmlFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myFile];  
NSXMLParser *parser= [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:xmlFile];
```

This is just an example implement your own login , use above two lines to get the path of local file.